# iTunes API - JSON Array Error Swift4, Req. to show in Collection View as Array

Tags: ios, json, swift

My json response is ,

```
{      resultCount = 32;
            results =     (
                        {
                    artistId = 909253;
                    artistName = "Jack Johnson";
                    country = USA;
                    currency = USD;
                    kind = "music-video";
                },
                        {
                    artistId = 909253;
                    artistName = "Jack Johnson";
                    country = UK;
                    currency = USD;
                    kind = "music-video";

                }
```

I have written code for view load to call the get method,

```
Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jackjohnson&entity=musicVideo").responseJSON  { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            if let json = response.result.value  //getting json
            {
                print(json)

                let jobsArray : NSArray  = json as! AnyHashable as! NSArray //converting json to NSArray
                if jobsArray.count > 0
                {
                    for object in jobsArray
                    {
                        if let singleDict = object as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            self.arrFavAdsList.add(singleDict)
                            print(self.arrFavAdsList)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                    //displaying data in tableview
                }

            }

        }
```

But its showing json array error.. I need to get the array response as dictionary and show it in my Collection View

Comment: What error do you get?  You shouldn't use `NSArray` in Swift. `as! anyHashable as! NSArray` is particularly ugly.  From your JSON you can see that the root isn't an array, it is a dictionary. The `results` key of that dictionary is an array.  I strongly suggest you look at `Codable` to parse your JSON

Comment: As suggested by @Paulw11 you can use Codable/Decodable to parse json, or else you can refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651826/2323806

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935997/how-to-update-table-view. There is an example how to parse JSON from `itunes.apple.com/search` with Decodable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare variables in your view controller or elsewhere

```
var mArray:[Music] = []
```

Try to use Codable/Decodable Json parse in order to fetch ApiResults,

```
struct ApiResults:Decodable {
    let resultCount: Int
    let results: [Music]
}

struct Music:Decodable {
    let artistId: Int?
    let artistName: String?
    let country: String?
    let currency: String?
    let kind: String?
}
```

Now, try in your viewdidload or call it as function where ever wish to be...

```
func callAPI() {

 guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jackjohnson&entity=musicVideo") else {return}

  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, response, error) in
  guard let data = data else {return}
           do
                {
       let apiressults = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResults.self, from: data)
                                for item in apiressults.results
             {if let track_Name = item.trackName, let artist_Name = item.artistName, let country = item.country, let currency = item.currency, let kind = item.kind
     {let musics = Music(artistId: artist_Id, artistName: artist_Name, country: country, currency: currency, kind: kind)
                     self.mArray = apiressults.results
                                       }
                                }
             DispatchQueue.main.async
                     {
                      self.collectionView.reloadData()
                     } }
                            catch let jsonError
                            {
                                print("Error:", jsonError)
                            }
                            }.resume()
    }
```

Now at last, as u mentioned in order to show it in collection view as array/list.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
               return mArray.count
            }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell // your cell identifier..
      cell.label1.text = mArray[indexPath.row].trackName
      cell.label2.text = mArray[indexPath.row].trackId
      cell.label3.text = mArray[indexPath.row].currency. 
///////like so for other stuffs which u need to show in collection view.
                    }
       return cell 
                }
```

Comment: Why this cumbersome optional dance and creating `Music` instances from `Music` instances? The iTunes search API sends reliably **all** keys in the `Music` dictionary.

Comment: @vadian, will u please edit for all keys in Music Dictionary

Comment: @AzeemRiverswave Just remove all question marks in `Music` and replace the entire `for item in apiressults.results { ... }` expression with `self.mArray = apiressults.results`

Answer (score 0):

Your full JSON content is the dictionary, So you need to convert first JSON string to a dictionary, Use following code to convert JSON into a dictionary, and then extract result array from dictionary and load into your `UICollectionview`

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON's content is a Dictionary and you cannot convert it that way. Here is a working version:

```
Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jackjohnson&entity=musicVideo").responseJSON { response in
    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let tracks = json["results"] as? Array<[String: Any]>, tracks.count > 0 {
        for track in tracks {
            // do your stuffs with track here.
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd prefer you to use Codable/Decodable to parse JSON in Swift. You can take a look at following example for reference:

```
struct APIResult: Codable {
    struct Track: Codable {
        let kind: String
        let artistName: String
        let name: String

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case kind
            case artistName
            case name = "trackName"
        }
    }

    let resultCount: Int
    let tracks: [Track]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case resultCount
        case tracks = "results"
    }
}

// and then use it like following:

Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jackjohnson&entity=musicVideo").response { response in
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let tracks = try! decoder.decode(APIResult.self, from: response.data!).tracks
    for track in tracks {
        // do your stuffs with track here.
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: please suggest how to call the collection view reload the list of array for each

Comment: I am not sure why you want to `call the collection view reload the list of array for each` since once you get the results, all the collection changed so I think your old code can still be used: `self.collectionView.reloadData()`, no?. Anyway, to answer your question lets check method `reloadItems(at:) ` of UICollectionView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditems